# SpringMVC: Serving XHTML

Tags: xhtml, spring-mvc, content-type

I have a annotated spring-mvc controller which gives some data to a jsp-view.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView editor(){

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("editor");
    model.addObject("profile", "default");
    model.addObject("extString", "[]");
    return model;
}
```

Now, in my application before which worked with classic http-servlets I added this to the responds:

```
response.setContentType("application/xhtml+xml");
```

Spring-MVC seems to deliver the content in plan old html. So my web-side has a mayor problem. I didn't find a solution for this on the web. 
Help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your jsp, you could put something like this on top:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="application/xhtml+xml; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
```